# Handling Null Values in MVC3 webgrid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

Can someone please explain me how to handle null values in mvc3 webgrid?

Comment: Could you be a little more specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is a little vague but I believe you can use the null coalescing operator `??`.

This question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6409157/webgrid-mvc3-handling-null-values-for-the-columns-asp-net) shows dealing with a null value using the ternary operator (`?:`) but I believe it could have been written:

```
grid.Column("Absend", format: (item) => item.AbsEnd ?? string.Empty)
```